# Curl получить POST запросом данные со страницы сайта в виде массива или переменных в PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

Вопрос довольно простой, с помощью cURL получить данные страницы в виде массива или отдельных переменных (не принципиально). Код внизу работает, но он выводит всю страницу сайта coingecko, а нужно чтобы данные 100 валют по типу "Название валюты" => "Стоимость" выводилось в виде массива.

**Пример:**

```
Bitcoin => 53,000.09$;

Ethereum => 2,450.00$
```

и все остальные валюты по такому же типу.

**Или в виде переменных:**

```
$Bitcoin = 53,000.09;

$Ethereum =  2,450.00;
```

Тоесть название валюты и ее стоимость и чтобы эти данные были в массиве с которыми можно будет работать в PHP.

Всевозможные библиотеки, регистрации на Coingecko, иные API пожалуйста, не предлагайте и агрегаторы для получения значений, нужно решить задачу именно через cURL.

Cпасибо за помощь.

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    // Включаем отображение ошибок:
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    // Адрес для парсинга:
    $url = 'http://www.coingecko.com/';
    

// Создаём новый сеанс:
    $curl = curl_init();
    

// Указываем адрес целевой страницы:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    
   

// О отключаем проверку SSL сертификата:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    

// Устанавливаем заголовки для имитации браузера:
    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: identity';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $headers[] = 'Host: ' . parse_url($url)['host'];
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
    $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
    $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    

// Разрешаем переадресацию:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    


// Запрещаем прямой вывод результата запроса:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
    

// Делаем сам запрос:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    
    

// Завершаем сеанс:
    curl_close($curl);
    
    

// Смотрим результат:

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Вам нужен парсер сайтов, напр. [phpQuery](https://snipp.ru/php/phpquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить следующие строчки кода, тогда вы получите страницу сайта в виде массива.

```
// Запрещаем прямой вывод результата запроса:
    
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    
    // Делаем сам запрос:
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);  
    
    $resultArray = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    
  
  
// Завершаем сеанс:


    
    curl_close($curl);
    

// Смотрим результат:


    
    
    echo'<pre>';
       print_r($resultArray);
    echo'</pre>';
```